# Keep general phone installation size (incl. IOS) to a minimum

Tags: iphone, disk-space, ios

I just bought an iPhone 5s and will receive it soon

It only has 16gb of RAM

I will clean install IOS 8 upgrade (this is best, no?)

Will the installation files self-delete after install?

And do you know some good tricks / guides / apps to keep IOS and other install sizes to a minimum? I mean clean up and delete unnecessary files etc.

Thanks

Comment: A simple guide, anything downloaded from the Web that you did not use for 3 or more moths delete it, if you need it you can always get it from the web again.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the files will auto-delete after installation. iOS has a really good file management system. There are not "tricks/guides/apps" to keep the install sizes to a minimum. This is not Android to clean up and delete unnecessary files, It's done automatically.

Comment: Ok, I guess I just delete apps I don't need

Comment: btw, if it was obvious to me that install files would auto-delete, I would not ask ;) And yes, ofc there are ways to increase space on the phone, I just don't know how.